# How to extract numbers used in string?

Tags: c++, string, numbers, extract

I've got a `std::string number = "55353"` and I want to extract the numbers that I've used in this string (5 and 3). Is there a function to do that? If so, please tell me it's name, I've been searching for quite a while now and still haven't found it...
UPD:
I've solved my problem (kinda)

```
std::string number(std::to_string(num));

std::string mas = "---------";              

int k = 0;                                  
for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {
    char check = number[i];                 
    for (int j = 0; j < mas.size(); j++) {
        if (check == mas[j])                
            break;                          
        if (check != mas[j] && check != mas[j+1]) {
            mas[k] = check;                 
            k++;                            
            break;                          
        }                                   
    }                                       
}                                           

mas.resize(k); mas.shrink_to_fit();
```

`std::string mas` will contain numbers that were used in `std::string number` which is a number converted to `std::string` using `std::to_string()`.

Comment: No, there's no standard function for doing this. You'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: How do I do it then? I've tried so much stuff, but it just won't work. I'm new to C++, please help.

Comment: Best option to stop being new to C++ is to learn. See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329) for inspiration.

Comment: `std::isdigit`, `std::set`, loop.

Comment: oh god, what have i done

Comment: You've asked a question but not shown any code that attempts to solve it. So the next step should be obvious: write some code, using the hing that @juanchopanza gave you.

Comment: `std::string::find`, `std::string::erase`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::string test_data= "55335";
char digit_to_delete = '5';
unsigned int position = test_data.find();
test_data.erase(position, 1);
cout << "The changed string: " << test_data << "\n";
```

The algorithm is to `find` the number (as a character) within the string.  The position is then used to `erase` the digit in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like homework, so I can guess what you forgot to tell us.

`mas` starts with ten `-`. If you spot a 5, you should replace the 6th (!) dash with a `'5'`. That "6th" is just an artifact of English. C++ starts to count at zero, not one. The position for zero is `mas[0]`, the first element of the array.

The one tricky bit is to understand that characters in a string aren't numbers. The proper term for them is "(decimal) digits". And to get their numerical value, you have to subtract `'0'` - the *character* zero. So `'5' - '0' == 5` - the character five minus the character zero is the *number* 5.